# How to fetch data from a Nested Array according a key in a array

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsarray, multidimensional-array

**Hello frnds actually i have a array of arrays as given below:-`**

```
parrent array{
    PrArr =
```

(

```
            {
                dt = "01-Apr-2012 11:15 PM\n";
                dur = "15\n\t\t";
                name = "Tez Special\n\t\t";
            },
                        {
                dt = "01-Apr-2012 11:30 PM\n\n";
                dur = "30\n\t\t";
                name = "Tez Tare\n\t\t";
            }
        );
        sid = "530\n";
    },

        {
        PrArr =         (

            {
                dt = "01-Apr-2012 11:20 PM\n";
                dur = "20\n\t\t";
                name = "Shiv Yog - Acharya Ishan Shivanandji\n\t\t";
            },
                        {
                dt = "01-Apr-2012 11:40 PM\n\n\n\t";
                dur = "20\n\t\t";
                name = "Param Pujya Swami HariChaitanya Puriji Maharaj\n\t\t";
            };
            sid = "560\n";
    },
```

}
**i want to fetch data according to sid in a array.**

Thanx in advance

Comment: Interesting question but little unclear. Which is your parent array? Is 'PrArr' parent array's elements(which are in turn arrays- as ur que implies)? have u used NSDictionay to store dt,dur,name as keys.?

Comment: PrArr is not parent array ...yes i used nsdictionary ..

Comment: yes thats only..my guess was right;PrArr is subarray.. Ok, so what logic have you used to store the data in PrArr. I mean it has data inside 2 curly braces & 'sid'. Extract this sid & sort according to requirements & then store in it array. Look for NSSortDescriptor. It will help you.

Comment: thanx hpiOS Coder .... i m going to check NSSortDescriptor

Comment: check my answer it help you to quickly sort as per you needs. Dont forget that sort-descriptor just specifies way of sorting. it dont sorts. Sorting is done by Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do find the dictionary where the sid is equal a something, then you will need to use [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789).

From apple documentation:

> Predicates provide a general means of specifying queries in Cocoa. The
>   predicate system is capable of handling a large number of domains, not
>   just—for example—Core Data or Spotlight. This document describes
>   predicates in general, their use, their syntax, and their limitations.

With NSPredicate you can find all sid that correspond to your search.

I will give you an example. Based on the array you posted here, you want to return the entry that have the sid equals to @"530\n", what you will need to do is:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sid LIKE %@",@"530\n"];
NSDictionary* entry = [[parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] objectAtIndex:0];
```

But if you are trying to sort your array based on the sid, you can use the [NSSortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Concepts/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001845-BAJEAIEE), that will return your array sorted based in the sid.

From apple documentation:

> A sort descriptor describes a comparison used to sort a collection of
>   objects. You create an instance of NSSortDescriptor that specifies the
>   property key to be sorted, and whether the comparison should be in
>   ascending, or descending order. A sort descriptor can also specify a
>   method to use when comparing the property key values, rather than the
>   default of compare:.
>
> It is important to remember that NSSortDescriptor does not sort
>   objects. It provides the description of how to sort objects. The
>   actual sorting is done by other classes, often NSArray or
>   NSMutableArray.

One example for you

```
NSSortDescriptor *sidDescriptor= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sid" ascending:YES];
NSArray* sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sidDescriptor];    
NSArray* sortedArray = [parentArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just tentatively scribbling it, Check if something like this helps you.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sidDescr = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sid" ascending:YES];
sortDescriptors =  [NSArray arrayByAddingObject:sidDescr];    
NSArray * sortedArr = [*yourparentarray* sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```